# JNI UnsatisfiedLinkError when using native function

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have a method of performing some operation using some external libraries.
To do this, I defined an interface `IMethod` and an abstract class `AMethod`:

```java
public interface IMethod {
    /**
     * Get a level by a certain method.
     *
     * @return The level obtained using this method.
     * @throws MethodUndefinedResultException If an error occurred in the method while obtaining the level.
     */
    Level getLevel() throws MethodUndefinedResultException;

    /**
     * Get method type.
     *
     * @return Enum method value.
     */
    Method getMethod();
}
```

```java
abstract class ALibrary implements IMethod {
    private final Logger log = LoggerWrapper.getLogger();
    private final Library library;

    public ALibrary(Library library) {
        this.library = library;
    }

    @Override
    public Level getLevel() throws MethodUndefinedResultException {
        try {
            linkWithLibrary();
            String nativeCallResult = makeNativeCall();
            return parseNativeCallResult(nativeCallResult);
        } catch (LibraryResolveException | LibraryNativeCallException | LibraryParsingException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            throw new MethodUndefinedResultException(library.getMethod(), e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Method getMethod() {
        return library.getMethod();
    }

    /**
     * Link with library for the native method.
     *
     * @throws LibraryResolveException If library is not available.
     */
    private void linkWithLibrary() throws LibraryResolveException {
        try {
            System.loadLibrary(library.getLibraryName());
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            throw new LibraryResolveException(library, e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Make native call for the level.
     *
     * @return Result of the native call.
     * @throws LibraryNativeCallException If the result does not contain a level.
     */
    protected abstract String makeNativeCall() throws LibraryNativeCallException;

    /**
     * Parse library native call result to the level.
     *
     * @param nativeCallResult Result of the native call.
     * @return Parsed level value.
     * @throws LibraryParsingException If the result of the native method call could not be parsed.
     */
    protected abstract Level parseNativeCallResult(String nativeCallResult)
            throws LibraryParsingException;
}
```

After this I implemented test class `TestMethod` that extends `AMethod` and implements `IMethod`:

```java
public class TestLibrary extends ALibrary implements IMethod {
    private static final Library LIBRARY = Library.Test;

    private final Logger log = LoggerWrapper.getLogger();

    public TestLibrary() {
        super(LIBRARY);
    }

    /**
     * A native method of the Test library that returns level.
     *
     * @return Level in numeric format.
     */
    private native String getlvl();

    @Override
    protected String makeNativeCall() throws LibraryNativeCallException {
        try {
            return new TestLibrary().getlvl();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            throw new LibraryNativeCallException(LIBRARY);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Level parseNativeCallResult(String nativeCallResult) throws LibraryParsingException {
        log.info(nativeCallResult);
        // TODO: Test with lib and remove stub
        throw new LibraryParsingException(LIBRARY, null);
    }
}
```

And use it as:

```java
IMethod testMethod = new TestLibrary();
testMethod.getLevel();
```

But I got `UnsatisfiedLinkError` from the `getlvl()` in the `makeNativeCall()` method of the `TestMethod` class that cause `LibraryNativeCallException`.

But when I'm doing something like:

```java
public class TestMethod {
    public native String getlvl();

    static {
        System.loadLibrary(Library.Test.getLibraryName());
    }

    public String getLevel() throws UnsatisfiedLinkError {
        return new TestMethod().getlvl();
    }
}
```

Everything works well. It seems to me that there is some kind of problem with an abstract class, but I can't figure out what it is. I would like to fix the new code and remove the old one.

Can you help please?

Comment: Add the full stacktrace of the error.

Comment: @aled Unfortunately there's no advanced stacktrace. `TestLibrary().getlvl();` just throws UnsatisfiedLinkError which wraps into my custom exceptions.

Comment: Your exception should wrap the original exception.

Comment: @aled And the original exception is UnsatisfiedLinkError, without any internal exceptions.

Comment: @aled I think I have figured out... If I change the java class name or its path in packages, do I need to recompile the C++ library? I came to this conclusion because my new java code finds external library, but can't call the function `getlvl()`.

Comment: and maybe regenerate the header file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, if I change the java code, I need to change and recompile the C/C++ code.

In the `testlib.cpp` I have this contract:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_lvl_method_library_impl_TestMethod_getlvl(JNIEnv * env, jobject jobj)
```

And when I use `TestMethod` everything works well, but with `TestLibrary` my code does not call `getlvl()`.

On the advice of @aled, I recompiled the library by changing the name of the function in it to:

```java
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_lvl_method_library_impl_TestLibrary_getlvl(JNIEnv * env, jobject jobj)
```

And the new code started working. 
Yaaaaas!